# (CSS) How to position the Div near to the bottom right corner of the browser Relatively to the Browser Size?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Look at this image:

[image]

I want to use a div to create a dialogbox that is near to the bottom right corner of the browser. The footer is **fixed** & its height is 50px & the dialogbox Div will lie right on top of the footer & to the bottom right corner of the browser as showed in the picture.

Note: the requirement is that that Div must be in that desired position **relatively** to the browser size. It means that when users shrink to extend the browser the div will be moved as well, but no matter how the div was moved, it should be always in that desired position as showed in the picture.

So, how can I do that in CSS?

Comment: So how to dothat in CSS? k k

Comment: What's your existing HTML and CSS look like?

Comment: If you present your html and css, i won't feel like doing someone else's homework.

Comment: @Naveen: I don't think a JSFiddle is required for this question. It's perfectly clear as it is.

Comment: Suppose you have a very long page with scrolling so that the footer is below the fold of the web page.  Where should the dialog element be position?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the element to stick regardless of scroll, use `position: fixed`:

```
{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 50px;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: will this work in all Browsers including the old ones & the very new ones?

Comment: @Kiti: `position:fixed` isn't supported in IE 6 and earlier, nor iOS before version... 5 possibly, nor Netscape 4, nor Mosaic... could you be more specific than "all browsers"?

Comment: so if users go to my website via IE6, whill they see the box? 
will it break my website?

Comment: If you have IE6 users, I feel sorry for them. They can’t even use gmail or youtube anymore... But you can always be nice and position it absolute for them using conditional comments: `<!--[if IE 6]><style>#mydiv{position:absolute}</style><![endif]-->`

Comment: Ok David, thax you very much for your help.

Comment: @Kiti: `position:fixed` isn't supported in IE 6, so it's ignored, so the dialog will be laid out as if it had `position:static`. Whether that counts as breaking your website is up to you.

Comment: thax u very much, anyway my acc has just got banned after i contributed so many useful questions.

Answer (score 0):

[`position:fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Fixed_positioning) positions elements relative to the browser's viewport:

```
.CLASS_OF_DIALOG_DIV {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 50px;
}
```

However, if your footer does not also have `position:fixed`, then it won't have the right position relative to your dialog.

And if your footer *does* have `position:fixed`, then it will obscure any page content that reaches (or goes past) the bottom of the browser viewport.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the css

```
#dialog{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:50px;
    right:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps man,

```
<div style="position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; width: 200px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid green;">
</div>
```

Eg:
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yuvaraj_b/EQQjh/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<div stlye="position:relative; z-index:1;">
  <div class="header"> header of website </div>
  <div clss="main"></div>
  <div clss="footer"> footer of website </div>
</div>
<div style="position:absolude;z-index:10000;right:0px;bottom:20px;"> dialog </div>
</body>
```

Comment: HTML actually has elements for headers and footers now: see http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#the-header-element and http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#the-footer-element

Answer (score 0):

Working demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EQQjh/2/)

You HTML could be

```
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2">
    </div>
</div>
```

In CSS

```
.div1{
   width: 100%;
   height: 500px; 
   border: 1px solid black; 
   position: relative 
}
.div2{
    position: absolute; 
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    width: 25%; 
    height: 100px; 
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: HTML actually has elements for headers and footers now: see http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#the-header-element and http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#the-footer-element

Comment: @MarcAudet: specifically, for `<div class="div">`.

Comment: Updated my answer :) TQ

Comment: Not sure what `height: 500px;` is for. Unless all browser viewports are 500 pixels tall, this won't fulfill the requirements in the question.

Comment: It turns out the footer is fixed, so the `position: fixed` solution is what the OP was looking for (in a rather elusive problem statement).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite The OP's problem statement is not very precise, and without any posted HTML, it was hard to guess what problem was being posed.

Comment: @MarcAudet: I actually think it's not too bad. Given that the OP stated the dialog should be positioned relatively to the browser's viewport and the footer, it's reasonable to assume that the footer is also positioned relatively to the browser's viewport. It's a hell of a lot more precise than most CSS layout queries on Stack Overflow. Regardless of that, Naveen's solution is still contrary to the details that *are* stated explicitly in the question. Therefore it doesn't answer the question. Therefore it's still worthy of a downvote.